# How to properly watch an object in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to use a Vue watcher on a computed object and it is not working at all. It works properly if it's just a string, but not if it's an object. I followed the Vue documentation but I am still getting nothing logged to the console when the object changes. The properties of the object and computed property are changing, as I have confirmed in Vue Tools. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```js
<v-btn small dark @click="test1.asdf = 'blah'">Test</v-btn>
    data() {
      return {
        test1: {},
      }
    },
    computed: {
      test() {
        return this.test1
      }
    },

    watch: {
      test: {
        handler: function(val, oldVal) {
          console.log(oldVal, val);
        },
        deep: true
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, its works fine

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{ test1 }}
    <hr />
    <button @click="test1.asdf = 'blah'">Click</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script >
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      test1: { asdf: "HEY" },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    test() {
      return this.test1;
    },
  },

  watch: {
    test: {
      handler: function (val, oldVal) {
        console.log(oldVal, val);
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I'd guess in your case you should add `.native` at end of your click event like this `@click.native="test1.asdf = 'blah'"`

Comment: you fixed it by adding `asdf` property to the `test1` object in data

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I love the fact that you just edited the answer to sound less rude. Small details that means a lot. Cheers

Comment: Yes adding "test1: { asdf: "HEY" }" does appear to fix the issue; however, the computed property is working regardless of the initial data there. It appears watcher's dont work at all when adding keys to an object?

Comment: @BadCoder It seems like it's a more complicated behavior than that. I just tried with `test1 = random()` to see if the watcher would be triggered after the second click (so after the property `asdf` has been created), but it didn't work either. Somehow Vue doesn't like it when we try to create a property that doesn't exist yet. However it works very well if you update the whole object instead of its property.

Comment: @Ryo what do you mean by update the whole object?

Comment: @BadCoder Updating (well, maybe I should say "replacing") the parent object instead of the property. For example `test1 = { asdf: 'blah' }`. By the way, I just realized I wrote `test1 = random()` in the last comment but I meant `test1.asdf = random()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried by replacing the whole object. It works pretty well, and there is no need to initialize your object with the `asdf` property in your data:

```
<v-btn small dark @click="test1 = { ...test1, asdf: 'blah'}">Test</v-btn>
```

The spread syntax `...test1` helps keeping other properties in the target object if there is any, so you can safely add the `asdf` property without worrying about losing anything.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vh72a3bs/22/

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info. It is odd that Vue works like this.

Comment: @BadCoder I agree. Personally in my projects with JS frameworks or libs, I always change the whole object so I'm sure any update stuff like watchers are properly triggered. This is, of course, if the object itself is not terribly huge (the performance concerns still remain). Glad my answer helped you though, please do not forget to mark it as best answer if you don't mind!

Answer (score 0):

@BadCoder Objects and Arrays are pass by reference in JavaScript, not pass by value. This means that when you add a key to the object as you are you doing in your question, you're just adding to the same Object. It's contents have changed but your variable `test1` is still referencing the original object and unaware that its contents have updated. The watcher doesn't pick this change up. You can add `deep: true` to your watcher as another answerer has suggested, but this only watches for a couple of levels deep, so not ideal if you have a large object with lots of nested data. The most reliable way to trigger a watcher when dealing with arrays or objects is to create a new instance of that object. You can achieve this with object destructing.
Something like,

```
<v-btn small dark @click="test1 = { ...test1, asdf: 'blah'}">Test</v-btn>
```

works because you're creating a new object (using the previous objects attributes, plus anything new), triggering the watcher.